# Developing native apps for ubuntu phone and tablet

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I wanna know which language should I use to develop native apps on ubuntu phone/tablet/tv ? Also, which IDE to use?

Shall I understand that ubuntu apps on PC could be easily ported on tablet and phone as well?